# Facebook Javascript function nested loops

Tags: javascript, dom-events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to do a loop to retrieve first my friends id's then with those id's I get the id of the page each user likes. I have this function but it only gets me the first user's likes not all user likes...

What am I doing wrong?

```
 FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        friendCount = response.data.length;
        for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
          friendId = response.data[i].id;
          FB.api('/'+friendId+'/likes', function(response) {
                         var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
            {
                 testdiv.innerHTML +=  response.data[i].id + '<br/>' ;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of 'response' - save the user IDs into another variable before reusing 'reponse'

edit: change the first few lines to:

```
 FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        friendCount = response.data.length;
        friendData = response.data;
        for( i=0; i<friendCount; i++) {
          friendId = friendData[i].id;
```

...

Comment: Hey Igy thank you... 
Can you please help me out with this, because i might have come up to this part using my logic, but i'm not good in javascript...

Answer (score 0):

```
 FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        friendCount = response.data.length;
        for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
          friendId = response.data[i].id;
          FB.api('/'+friendId+'/likes', function(response2) { // use another variable
          var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
        for(j=0;j<response2.data.length;j++) // use another var here also
            {
                 testdiv.innerHTML +=  response2.data[i].id + '<br/>' ;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it still gives me limited number, i mean, do you think there might be anything wrong with the code? at least how it is programmed?